# How do I get different timezone date in javascript?

Tags: javascript, datetime, time

I have timezone stored with me in a var like: timezone = "America/Los_Angeles".
So by providing this timezone, can I get the LA's current time in Javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Here's an article](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://articles.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/5100-10878_11-6016329.html) that illustrates how this could be done assuming you know the timezone offset.